# How are clojure namespaces looked up?

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen, noir

To start off I am not a Java programmer, so it would be helpful if your answers are not defined in terms of Java (inasmuch as that makes sense).

I have a leiningen project (specifically a web project using [noir](http://webnoir.org/)) using what seems to be a common pattern of putting your clojure source files in `src/YOUR-NAMESPACE/`. So far I've had success adding directories and files, and I have been using the file path as the basis for the `ns` (following the pattern I see in the generated code).

I added a new file that did not work, and I'm wondering why. It's path is `PROJECT-ROOT/src/bayou/lib/api-helpers.clj` and its namespace is `(ns bayou.lib.api-helpers)`. The specific error I'm getting is:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate bayou/lib/api_helpers__init.class or bayou/lib/api_helpers.clj on classpath`

**What are all the steps one as to take in order for clojure to recognize a namespace?**

Comment: After I wrote this question I also found this helpful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223190/what-are-common-conventions-for-using-namespaces-in-clojure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the hyphen in the namespace.

From the *Joy of Clojure*

> HYPHENS/UNDERSCORES If you decide to name your namespaces with
>   hyphens, à la my-cool-lib, then the corresponding source file must be
>   named with underscores in place of the hyphens (my_cool_lib.clj).

Here is the underlying explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4451693/32174