# Clojure namespacing converting - to _

Tags: clojure, noir

The error as shown on the Noir error page: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate boundaries/lat_long__init.class or boundaries/lat_long.clj on class path`

The code that requires it:

```
(ns boundaries.views.boundary
  (:use noir.core
        hiccup.core
        hiccup.page-helpers)
  (:require
    [boundaries.lat-long :as lat-long]
    [noir.response :as resp]))
```

Why is it looking for `lat_long` instead of the specified `lat-long`? boundaries/lat-long.clj exists as well as the corresponding boundaries.lat-long namespace.

Comment: Hi Chris, I think this is the response: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4420944/151650

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the JVM does not allow `-`s in class names so the Clojure compiler converts them to `_`s

the problem is most likely with the project.clj dependencies.

When diagnosing this sort of issue:

- is the namespace available from the REPL?
- does the .class file appear in the lib directory for the project?
- re-run `lein deps`

Comment: I see. As I'm learning, I'd like to adhere to conventions. Do Clojure developers generally adopt camelcase as in Java?

Comment: I'm really not the one to ask about java conventions, hopefully someone will comment... It is perfectly fine to use - in the names, I just like not to. i'll remove that from my post, it's too opinionated for SO IMHO ;-)

Comment: Oh no! Fortunately I want to make things that other people use, and as such conventions and personal aesthetics are important

Comment: @dAni but if the compiler converts them to _ then what do I do? Name the files with _ but the ns with -?

Comment: Yes. Look at the Clojure source code for plenty of examples. I was also quite surprised/annoyed :), now I just don't realize about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the boundaries/lat-long.clj to boundaries/lat_long.clj.

Note that you don't have to change the namespace name. The clojure convention is to use "-" for functions and namespace names.

From Stuart Sierra response at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451693/151650: "It's a necessary workaround for Java interoperability."