# How do you specify the classpath with Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

In Clojure, I have a Leiningen project with my source in

```
/src/project/core.clj
```

I want to add a subdirectory to this. Eg.

```
/src/project/examples/example-one.clj
```

In my core.clj file I try to pull in from

```
project.examples.example-one
```

But lein compile still tells me

```
Could not locate project/examples/example_one__init.class or project/examples/example_one.clj on classpath:
```

Do you have to explicitly update project.clj file if you add a subdirectory to your main code directory? (I don't see that the main code directory itself is given there explicitly.)

Answer (score 7):

if your namespace contains dashes, the corresponding file should contain underscores instead of those dashes. You can read about the reason in here:

[why-does-clojure-convert-dashes-in-names-to-underscores-in-the-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420944/why-does-clojure-convert-dashes-in-names-to-underscores-in-the-filesystem)

Unless you add different source codes like Java, Groovy etc... by default lein will include all the namespaces in the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ... seems I can't have a hyphen in file name?

Kind of weird for a Lisp dialect, now I've got used to using hyphens as the default separator in my function names.